# string to pandas dataframe

Tags: string, pandas, delimiter

following the parsing of a large pdf document I end up with string in the format in python:

```
Company Name;(Code) at End of Month;Reason for Alteration No. of Shares;Bond Symbol, etc.; Value, etc.; after Alteration;Remarks
Shares;Shares
TANSEISHA CO.,LTD.;(9743)48,424,071;0
MEITEC CORPORATION;(9744)31,300,000;0
TKC Corporation;(9746)26,731,033;0
ASATSU-DK INC.;(9747);42,155,400;Exercise of Subscription Warrants;0;May  2013 Resolution based 1;0Shares
May  2013 Resolution based 2;0Shares
```

Would it be possible to transform this into a pandas dataframe as follows where the columns are delimited by the ";". So looking at the above section from the string my df should look like:

```
Company Name    (Code) at End of Month    Reason for Alteration  ....
Value,etc       after Alteration          Remarks Shares .....
```

As additional problem my rows don't always have the same number of strings delimited by ";", meaning that I would need to find a way to see my columns( I don't mind setting like a dataframe with 15 columns and delete afterwards those II do no need)
Thanks

Comment: I vote no!  I can't make out what logic gets us from the text to the dataframe you've shown.

Answer (score 0):

I would split your read in string into a list of list. Possibly use regex to find the beginning of each record *(or at least use something that you know where it shows up, it looks like (Code) at End of Month might work)* and slice your way through. Something like this:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

# Start your list of list off with your expected headers
mystringlist = [["Company Name", 
                 "(Code) at End of Month", 
                 "Reason for Alteration",
                 "Value,etc",
                 "after Alteration",
                 "Remarks Shares"]]

# This will be used to store the start and end indexes of each record
indexlist = []

# A recursive function to find the start location of each record. It expects a list of 1s and 0s
def find_start(thestring, startloc=0):
    if startloc >=len(thestring):
        return
    else:
        foundindex = thestring.find("1",startloc)
        indexlist.append(foundindex)
        return find_start(thestring, foundindex+1)


# Split on your delimiter
mystring = thestring.split(";")

# Use a list comprehension to make your list of 1s 
# and 0s based on the location of a fixed regular expressible record
stringloc = "".join([1 if re.match(x, "\(\d+\)\d+,\d+,\d+") else 0 for x in mystring])

find_start(stringloc)

# Make your list of list based on found indexes
# We subtract 1 from the index position because we want the element
# that immediately precedes the element we find (it's an easier regex 
# to make when it's a consistent structure.
for x in indexlist:
    if mystringlist.index(x)+1 != len(indexlist):
        mystringlist.append(mystring[x-1:indexlist[indexlist.index(x)+1]-1])

# Turn mystring list into a data frame
mydf = pd.DataFrame(mystringlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice opportunity to use `StringIO` to make your result look like an open file handle so that you can just use `pd.read_csv`:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: from StringIO import StringIO

In [3]: s = """Company Name;(Code) at End of Month;Reason for Alteration No. of Shares;Bond Symbol, etc.; Value, etc.; after Alteration;Remarks
   ...: Shares;Shares
   ...: TANSEISHA CO.,LTD.;(9743)48,424,071;0
   ...: MEITEC CORPORATION;(9744)31,300,000;0
   ...: TKC Corporation;(9746)26,731,033;0
   ...: ASATSU-DK INC.;(9747);42,155,400;Exercise of Subscription Warrants;0;May  2013 Resolution based 1;0Shares
   ...: May  2013 Resolution based 2;0Shares"""

In [4]: pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep=";")
Out [4]:                    Company Name (Code) at End of Month Reason for Alteration No. of Shares                  Bond Symbol, etc.   Value, etc.              after Alteration  Remarks
0                        Shares                 Shares                                 NaN                                NaN           NaN                           NaN      NaN
1            TANSEISHA CO.,LTD.       (9743)48,424,071                                   0                                NaN           NaN                           NaN      NaN
2            MEITEC CORPORATION       (9744)31,300,000                                   0                                NaN           NaN                           NaN      NaN
3               TKC Corporation       (9746)26,731,033                                   0                                NaN           NaN                           NaN      NaN
4                ASATSU-DK INC.                 (9747)                          42,155,400  Exercise of Subscription Warrants           0.0  May  2013 Resolution based 1  0Shares
5  May  2013 Resolution based 2                0Shares                                 NaN                                NaN           NaN                           NaN      NaN
```

Note that it does look like there are some obvious data cleanup problems to tackle from here, but that should at least give you a start.